# Typescript Generic dictionary of constructors, type mismatch

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm making a set of classes which store objects. The end user can pick which class to use by specifying its type as a string through a dropdown.

To do this, I'm making a dictionary of constructors `ObjStorerDictionary` which will construct the classes which store the objects.

However, when I do so, I get an error like

```
Type 'typeof FooMaker' is not assignable to type 'ObjStorerConstructor<StoredObj>'.
  Types of parameters 'storedObj' and 'storedObj' are incompatible.
    Property 'fooProperty' is missing in type 'StoredObj' but required in type 'Foo'.ts(2322)
```

Additionally, eslint wants me to not use `any` in the `fromJson` function.

How can I use templates correctly to fix these errors?

```
interface StoredObj {
    name: string;
    [key: string]: unknown;
};

interface ObjStorer<SpecificStoredObj extends StoredObj> {
    makeStoredObj: () => SpecificStoredObj
}

export interface ObjStorerConstructor<SpecificStoredObj extends StoredObj> {
    new(storedObj: SpecificStoredObj): ObjStorer<SpecificStoredObj>
}


/////////////// FooMaker ////////////////
interface Foo extends StoredObj {
    name: "Foo",
    fooProperty: string
}

class FooMaker implements ObjStorer<Foo>{
    constructor(storedObj: Foo) {
        // do stuff
    }
    makeStoredObj(): Foo {
        return { name: "Foo", fooProperty: "fooo" }
    }
}

/////////////// BarMaker ///////////////
interface Bar extends StoredObj {
    name: "Bar",
    barProperty: string
}

class BarMaker implements ObjStorer<Bar>{
    constructor(storedObj: Bar) {
        // do stuff
    }
    makeStoredObj(): Bar {
        return { name: "Bar", barProperty: "baaar" }
    }
}

////////////// ObjStorerDictionary ///////////////
const ObjStorerDictionary: Record<string, ObjStorerConstructor<StoredObj>> = {
    "Foo": FooMaker, // ERROR HERE
    "Bar": BarMaker, // ERROR HERE
}

const constructObjectStorerFromJson = (name: string, args: not_any) => {
    return ObjStorerDictionary[name](args);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that functions are contravariant by their parameter types. A workaround that I would suggest is using `satisfies` with `ObjStorerConstructor<any>`: https://tsplay.dev/w25RjW

Comment: Your example code has at least one typo at `ObjStorerCollection`; could you make sure you're providing a [mre]?  The type you've annotated is indeed incorrect because, according to that type, I should be able to write `new ObjStorerDictionary.Foo({name: ""})` but `FooMaker` wouldn't be happy with that.  Given your implementation I'd say you should just *not* annotate the type and make your retrieval function generic, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WJAzDm), but presumably you have some use case you're not showing which would make that inappropriate? How should we proceed here?

Comment: I've fixed the minimum reproducible example (yes, this is minimal, I have stripped out a LOT already). Thanks for the suggestion about not including the types - this is working; but now I'm facing another issue: I don't want to use 'any' in the arguments for the constructor function... Any ideas?

Comment: @acenturyandabit There's nothing wrong with using `any` here. If you detest `any` that much, you can remove the `satisfies` part like in jcalz's playground link. The use of `any` here is safe and doesn't "spread". In fact, it's exactly what we need. We don't care what's inside `ObjStorerConstructor`.